# Reuse the same DataSet without memory issues

Tags: .net, ado.net, dataset

I am working on a .NET 3.5 project and will be using a DataSet with multiple DataTables and relationships between the DataTables.  I will be fetching a certain amount of records from SQL to fill the DataTables then process those records.  After I am finished processing the records, I want to clear out the DataSet and fetch the next set of records.  I have been reading that the Clear() method does not clear the rows from memory.  How can I reuse the DataSet without causing my memory to continue to increase over the life of fetching records?

Comment: Just change your selection criteria and call Fill again. You only need to mess about with the dataset if the tables or relationships change and then you'd just create a new dataset and pass that to your processing functions.

Comment: My concern here is about memory.  This process will be working on many thousands of records running for many hours.  I need to make sure the memory is managed correctly.

Comment: But once  DataRow is no longer referenced, the GC should get rid of it, Clear or Fill will do that. Looks like premature optimisation to me, find out if your concern is justifed, a simple POC Style trial will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN states that [the `DataSet.Clear` method clears the DataSet of any data by removing all rows in all tables.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.clear.aspx).  It will leave all tables and relations intact, but clear out all rows.

Where did you read otherwise?

Comment: If you read the response from a Microsoft employee at the following link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/41e1b19a-b5ee-4cf2-ac1e-ff0c9a35b961 you will see that he state the following: DataSet.Clear() and DataSet.Dispose() won’t make the rows cleared by GC.   .Clear() method will remove all the data rows in every datatable inside the dataset.   Also, the .Dispose() method is implemented by the base class of the DataSet MarshalByValueComonent, so it does not release the managed resources of dataset.

Comment: That's saying rows are cleared, meta data (tables relations etc are not), which is good, becasue it's unlikely that you want them to be. If the meta data was different each run then null or assign it to a new one etc